# Android Market activity intent - no activity found

Tags: android

The android docs state that I should be able to do the following to start the android market activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.android.example"));
startActivity(intent);
```

However, I get this error:

```
No activity found to handle Intent.
```

Do I need to explicitly create an activity in my app?

Comment: Is Market Application installed on your device?

Comment: No it isn't, well I can't find the icon for it - does that mean its not installed?  I'm using an emulator, how would I go about installing it on the emulator?

Comment: Give it a try on real device. Where Market App is installed.

Comment: I can't as I don't have a real device, not for the time being anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Adil is correct on this one; You need the android marketplace app on the emulator but by default its not installed. It has to be installed manually like any other .apk installation.

http://blog.varunkumar.me/2010/11/how-to-install-android-market-in-google.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to start your emulator using a Google APIs Image instead of standard Android, these are available from the SDK manager along side the normal android SDK

They're usually labelled like: "Google APIs by Google Inc. Android API 10" obviously dependent on the API version you want.

Comment: So do these images have the marketplace app by default installed?